# route structure in nodejs & expressjs

Tags: node.js, npm

I have following Application structure

```
/routes
  - index.js
dbconfig.js
dbresources.js
server.js
```

### 1. Content of `/routes/index.js`

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  console.log("Routes Successfully");
  sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM users_tbl").success(function(rows) {
    res.format({
      json: function() {
        res.send(rows);
      }
    });
    // res.jsonp(rows);
  }).error(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

### 2. Content of dbresources.js

```
module.exports = {
    database: {
        name: "dbproject",
        host: "root",
        password: ""
    }
}
```

### 3. Content of dbconfig.js

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')
    , mysql = require('mysql');

config = require("./dbresources");
db = config.database;

var sequelize = new Sequelize(db.name, db.host, db.password, {
    dialect: 'mysql'
});
```

### 4. Content of server.js

```
var express   = require('express')
  , http      = require('http')
  , app       = express()
  , http      = require('http')
  , routes    = require('./routes')
  , path      = require('path');

app.configure(function() {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.set(express.methodOverride());
    app.set(express.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'));
});

app.get('/user', routes.index);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("\n\n\tNode (Express) server listening on port " + app.get('port'))
});
```

When i am running my apps using node and fire localhost:5000/user. It shows me following error.

```
ReferenceError: sequelize is not defined
```

Comment: I know why this error is thrown; How can i provide reference of my dbconfig file to my routes files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is exactly what's wrong. You're using `sequelize` without defining it first it in /routes/index.js. If it's the var you've created in dbconfig, you first need to expose it like so:

```
// The rest of the code...
exports.sequelize = sequelize;
```

and import it in `/routes/index.js` like so:

```
var sequelize = require('./dbconfig').sequelize;
// The rest of the code...
```